# How to make SwiftUI NavigationLink work in edit mode?

Tags: swiftui, navigationlink

I have a list of items. Clicking on one should push a new view to the navigation stack. I notice the `NavigationLink` doesn't work if the list is in edit mode. Is there a way to control that? I need it to work in edit mode.

```
List {
    ForEach(segments) { segment in
        NavigationLink(destination: EditSegmentView(segment: segment)) {
            Text(segment.title)
        }
    }.onDelete(perform: onDelete)
     .onMove(perform: onMove)
}.environment(\.editMode, $alwaysTrue)
```

Comment: The link not working in edit mode is expected behaviour. If you imagine it from the user standpoint they would not want to be editing a list and accidentally navigate into one of the items they are editing.
What is it you are actually trying to achieve by keeping it in edit mode?

Comment: I'm editing a list of exercises in a workout. You can add/remove/move exercises in the list, and you can also drill down to edit a particular exercise (changes it's name, duration, etc.) I'm porting from UITableView code. I thought the UI was okay before. The delete button and move handles are separate from the name text, which triggers the navigate.

Comment: Arguably you are fighting upstream in trying to both activate edit mode and allow navigation. You should find a new way to achieve the desired UI.

Comment: I'll have to think about how I might redesign my app to work like that, but for now I just want to port parts of it to SwiftUI, if I can. I'm okay with being coaxed in a direction by a UI framework, but if SwiftUI is too restrictive I may not like it. For now, I have something working which I just posted in an answer.

Comment: I don't think that's expected behaviour. apple's contacts app in iOS does what Rob N is trying to do

Answer (score 9):

I now have this working the way I wanted. I used a different `NavigationLink` initializer, with the `tag` and `selection` arguments. It seems to work well, but I don't know if this is the intended use of that initializer, because the documentation is painfully sparse.

```
@State var segmentSelection: Segment.ID? = nil

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ...
        List {
            ForEach(workout.segments) { segment in
                NavigationLink(destination: EditSegmentView(segment: segment),    
                               tag: segment.id,
                               selection: self.$segmentSelection) {
                                Text(segment.title)
                }
                .onTapGesture(perform: { self.segmentSelection = segment.id })
            }.onDelete(perform: onDelete)
             .onMove(perform: onMove)
        }.environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(.active))
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: is this line together with the selection and tag initialiser that makes this work:.onTapGesture(perform: { self.segmentSelection = segment.id }). can use it to make a custom picker too. thanks!